# How to create a single dynamic block for a module from a map or object definition?

Tags: terraform

If I want to define a lambda function with a VPC config. I can do it like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "..."
  ...

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = ["..."]
    security_group_ids = ["..."]
  }
}
```

I would like to create the lambda in a terraform module and define the `vpc_config` in the module definition. I can define the module like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "..."
  ...

  dynamic "vpc_config" {
    for_each = var.vpc_configs
    content {
      subnet_ids   = vpc_config.value["subnet_ids"]
      security_group_ids = vpc_config.value["security_group_ids"]
    }
  }
}

variable "vpc_configs" {
  type = list(object({
    subnet_ids = list(string)
    security_group_ids = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

And then use it:

```
module "my_lambda" {
  source = "./lambda"
  ...

  vpc_configs = [
    {
      subnet_ids         = ["..."]
      security_group_ids = ["..."]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, since there is only one `vpc_config` block allowed there is no point in defining the variable as a list. I would prefer the following syntax:

```
module "my_lambda" {
  source = "./lambda"
  ...

  vpc_config = {
    subnet_ids         = ["..."]
    security_group_ids = ["..."]
  }
  # or:
  #vpc_config {
  #  subnet_ids         = ["..."]
  #  security_group_ids = ["..."]
  #}
}
```

However, I can't figure out if it is possible to define a variable like this and then use it in a dynamic block. I defined it as a list in the first place because I don't always need a VPC config and this way I can simply leave the list empty and no VPC config will be created. Is there a way to create an optional `vpc_config` block through a simple map or object definition?

Comment: Please update the question to explicitly enumerate your objectives here. From what I gather, you want at least 1. var declaration possible of type `object` 2. a dynamic block for a resource within the module 3. conditional dynamic block declaration 4. possibly also declaring as type `map` if necessary, but preferably not `list` 5. block declaration within the module declaration (not currently possible in TF HCL2 DSL by the way). Please explicitly clarify.

Comment: @MattSchuchard you already got the gist of it. The object declaration would be nice to get a type check on the defined fields. The block declaration was just an idea of mine, I didn't know if it is some special feature built-in in terraform or just a object declaration with a name. Beside from that I'm mainly wondering if I can have the optional dynamic block declaration without having to use an empty list to leave out the dynamic block if not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dynamic` blocks work by generating one block for each element in a collection, if any, whereas you want to define a variable that is an optional non-collection value. Therefore the key to this problem is to translate from a single value that might be `null` (representing absence) into a list of zero or one elements.

Due to how commonly this arises, Terraform has a concise way to represent that conversion using [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat), `[*]`. If you apply it to a value that *isn't* a list, then it will [implicitly convert it into a list of zero or one elements](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat#single-values-as-lists), depending on whether the value is null.

The example in the documentation I just linked to shows a practical example of this pattern. The following is essentially the same approach, but adapted to use the resource type that you are using in your question:

```
variable "vpc_config" {
  type = object({
    subnet_ids = list(string)
    security_group_ids = list(string)
  })
  default = null
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "..."
  ...

  dynamic "vpc_config" {
    for_each = var.vpc_config[*]
    content {
      subnet_ids         = vpc_config.value.subnet_ids
      security_group_ids = vpc_config.value.security_group_ids
    }
  }
}
```

The default value of `var.vpc_config` is `null`, so if the caller doesn't set it then that is the value it will take.

`var.vpc_config[*]` will either return an empty list or a list containing one `vpc_config` object, and so this dynamic block will generate either zero or one `vpc_config` blocks depending on the "null-ness" of `var.vpc_config`.

Answer (score 1):

so you are wanting a conditional dynamic block

you could possibly get away with it by doing a check similar to the one on the object below

```
dynamic "vpc_config"{
for_each = length(var.vpc_config) > 0 ? {config=var.vpc_config}: {}
content{
...
}
}
```

if no vpc_config is passed in the module then the input variable should default to something like an empty object {}, that way the dynamic conditional check will still work if no config is passed

Comment: How would I access the values of the config inside of the `content` block?

Comment: @kiritsuku via the `each` variable (`each.key`, and `each.value`).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it doesn't seem to be possible what I want to do (building an optional type safe configuration through an object definition without having to nest it in a list).

Instead I now use the lambda module provided by Terraform:

```
module "email_lambda" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "3.3.1"

  function_name = "${var.stack_name}-email"
  handler       = "pkg.email.App::handleRequest"
  runtime       = "java11"
  architectures = ["x86_64"]
  memory_size   = 512
  timeout       = 30
  layers        = [aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer.arn]

  create_package         = false
  local_existing_package = "../email/target/email.jar"

  environment_variables = {
    # https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = "-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"
  }

  vpc_subnet_ids         = module.vpc.private_subnets
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.lambda_security_group.id]

  attach_policies = true
  policies = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole",
  ]
  number_of_policies = 1

  attach_policy_json = true
  policy_json = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "SESBulkTemplatedPolicy"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [...]
        Action = [
          "ses:SendEmail",
          "ses:SendRawEmail",
          "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
          "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

As one can see in this configuration I had to set the VPC parameters individually and in case of the policy I had to specify a boolean parameter to tell Terraform that the configuration was set (I even had to specify the length of the provided list). Looking at the source code of the module reveals that there may not be a better way how to achieve this in the most up to date version of Terraform.